# Can a PDF-1.3 be a PDF/A?

Tags: pdf, pdfa

I have a PDF document which is supposed to be PDF/A conform, but the metadata states that it is a PDF-1.3 document. Can a PDF-1.3 document be conform with the rules of PDF/A?

Note that the first version of PDF/A is based on PDF-1.4 - hence my confusion.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF/A-1 specification (ISO 19005 part 1) states

> #### 5.1 General
>
> This part of ISO 19005 defines a file format for representing electronic documents known as “PDF/A-1.”
> Conforming PDF/A-1 files shall adhere to all requirements of PDF Reference as modified by this part of
> ISO 19005.

"PDF Reference" previously is defined as

> #### 4 Notation
>
> ...
>
> For the purposes of this part of ISO 19005, references to the “*PDF Reference*” are to *PDF Reference: Adobe
> Portable Document Format*, version 1.4, 3rd ed., as amended by *Errata for PDF Reference*, 3rd ed. [...]

Section 5.1 continues:

> Neither the version number in the header of a PDF file nor the value of the **Version** key in the document catalog dictionary shall be used in determining whether a file is
> in accordance with this part of ISO 19005.

As these are the only *metadata* that can *state that it is a PDF-1.3 document*, **this statement of version MUST NOT be used in determining whether a file is PDF/A-1.**

Thus, concerning your question:

> stijndg> *Can a PDF-1.3 document be conform with the rules of PDF/A?*

Yes, it can.

It merely has to

1. adhere to all requirements of PDF Reference, version 1.4 and
2. adhere to the requirements of ISO 19005 part 1 of Level A conformance or Level B conformance.

Furthermore Section 5.1 *recommends*:

> Features described in PDF specifications prior to Version 1.4 which are not explicitly
> described in *PDF Reference* should not be used.

But "should" indicates that this is a *recommendation*, so if for some reason the use of such features cannot be prevented, this does not keep a PDF from being PDF/A conform.